# HTML5 form with jQuery Mobile will not submit

Tags: jquery, html

I started working from an example somewhere and built this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        jQuery(window).ready(initiate_geolocation);

        function initiate_geolocation() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query,handle_errors);
        }

        function handle_errors(error)
        {
            switch(error.code)
            {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
                break;

                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
                break;

                case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timed out");
                break;

                default: alert("unknown error");
                break;
            }
        }

        function handle_geolocation_query(position){
            document.geo.lat.value=position.coords.latitude;
            document.geo.lon.value=position.coords.longitude;   
        }
    </script>
    <title>GPS data collection</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="processgeo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="geo" id="geo">
        <fieldset>
        <label for="lat">Lat</label>
            <input type="text" id="lat" name="lat" />
            <br />
        <label for="lon">Lon</label>
            <input type="text" id="lon" name="lon" />
            <br />
        <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
            <br />
        <label for="type">Type</label>
            <select name="type" id="type">
                <option value="entrance">entrance</option>
                <option value="intersection">intersection</option>
                <option value="parking">parking</option>
            </select>
            <br />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send data" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have tried all sorts of modifications, but the form will not submit. When I tap the submit button it just flashes, but makes no attempt to load the action file.

One thing I found is that if I strip all the script tags out, the form submits just fine. Why would including jQuery coding into the page prevent it from submitting? I am not trying to do any validation on the inputs.

I have verified the action file "processgeo.php" exists, and have even tried setting the action to post to itself. Same results.

UPDATE 2012-01-17:

I kept tinkering with this and it started working. I don't recall now what single item changed to let it function.  Comparing to the code posted above, I see these changes:

1. Added `<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` in the head section.
2. Changed form to enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Will edit again if I find the specific item that made it work.

Comment: Have you tried data-ajax="false" on your form? By default, JQM submits form posts as an AJAX call. 

Check out : http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html for more.

Comment: No, I hadn't tried that. That is good to know, thank you.  At some point when I was experimenting with things, it started working. In looking at it, I don't see anything that is significantly different. I'll try to update my original posting with current code.

Answer (score 1):

Im thinking this is related to the enc type, why is it a multipart form?
try: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't recall where I picked up that form type. I changed it to your recommendation, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: i cant test it with your .php, but if you say that the form is working without jquery, maybe the submit action is being disabled by jquery. What do you mean by flashes?

Comment: Nicholas - By "flashing" I meant that it appears to just reload itself... screen goes white very briefly then it all reappears.